# how to solve kong first reqtest delay problem, how to restrict access to some routes, how to do instrumentaion

Tags: docker, instrumentation, api-gateway, kong, zipkin

I have a microservices structure with a few services based on python/Django

The structure is as below:

user <===> **kong** <===> alpha <===> **kong** <===> beta <===> **kong** <===> gamma

this is my `kong.yml` declarative configuration:

```
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: alpha-beta-gamma-live
    host: alpha
    port: 8000
    protocol: http
    path: /beta/gamma/live
    routes:
      - name: alpha-beta-gamma-live
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /alpha/beta/gamma/live
        strip_path: true

  - name: beta-gamma-live
    host: beta
    port: 8000
    protocol: http
    path: /gamma/live
    routes:
      - name: beta-gamma-live
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /beta/gamma/live
        strip_path: true

  - name: gamma-live
    host: gamma
    port: 8000
    protocol: http
    path: /live
    routes:
      - name: gamma-live
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /gamma/live
        strip_path: true
plugins:
  - name: correlation-id
    config:
      header_name: X-Kong-Correlation-ID
      generator: uuid
      echo_downstream: true
  - name: zipkin
    config:
      local_service_name: kong
      http_endpoint: http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans
      sample_ratio: 1
      include_credential: true
      traceid_byte_count: 16
      header_type: preserve
      default_header_type: b3
      tags_header: Zipkin-Tags
```

and this is the docker-compose file to run kong

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: kong-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  kong:
    container_name: kong
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.40
    healthcheck:
      test: [ “CMD”, “curl”, “-f”, “http://kong:8000” ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=off
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/kong/declarative/kong.yml
    ports:
      - "8444:8444"
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
```

from within alpha service I use python's `requests` library to call an endpoint of beta that use python's `requests` library to call `/live` endpoint of gamma as below

**alpha**

```
version: '3'

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: kong-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  alpha:
    container_name: alpha
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.11
    ports:
      - "8011:8000"
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: secret-key
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def beta_gamma_live(request):

    res_kong = requests.get("http://kong:8000/beta/gamma/live")

    return Response({
        "chained-alpha-beta-gamma-status-check-through-kong": res_kong.status_code,
    }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**beta**

```
version: '3'

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: kong-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  beta:
    container_name: beta
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.12
    ports:
      - "8012:8000"
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: secret-key
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def gamma_live(request):

    res_kong = requests.get("http://kong:8000/gamma/live")

    return Response({
        "chained-beta-gamma-status-check-through-kong": res_kong.status_code,
    }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**gamma**

```
version: '3'

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: kong-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  gamma:
    container_name: gamma
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.13
    ports:
      - "8013:8000"
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: secret-key
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def live(request):
    return Response({"status": "Success"}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

**The First Question**

- When I send a request http://127.0.0.1/gamma/live it takes 20 seconds to return the response.
  But from the second time, it takes milliseconds
- all requests sent to http://127.0.0.1/alpha/beta/gamma/live take 40 seconds

I have found this issue about it

https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/3058

**Is there a way to fix/address this problem?**

---

**Second question**

I run Zipkin UI using a docker container as below

```
version: '3'

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: kong-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  zipkin:
    container_name: zipkin
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.41
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
```

When I open Zipkin UI on http://127.0.0.1:9411, The trace shows me three requests as below:

- ##########################  ~ 60 s
- ################  ~ 40 s
- #######  ~ 20 s

[image]

While it should be like this

- #########  ~ 20  s
- -.-.-.-.-.-.- #########  ~ 20  s
- -.-.-.-.--.-.-.-.-.-.-.- #########  ~ 20  s

In order to achieve this, I need to instrument each of the services using a library in the list below:

https://zipkin.io/pages/tracers_instrumentation

**Question 2 part 1**: What Should I do for python that is clean and easy to use?

**Question 2 part 2**: is there a way not to have to do it? I am looking for latency tracing that is language-agnostic and can be done through kong so that I don't have to add anything to the services alpha, beta, gamma